# Footer loads link from Woocommerce hook

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, hook

I have added function for Woocommerce single product hook and it crash footer on product page. It loads the last link from function to footer.

Function:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product', 'gazety' );

function gazety(){
    echo '<section class="gazety">
        <h2>Mogłeś przeczytać o mnie</h2>
        <div class="gazety_lst">
            <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                    <div class="gazety_box">
                            <div class="scl_ico gazety"><a href="https://e-biznes.pl/zwykly-milioner-niezwykle-zycie/" target="_blank"><img src="https://pawelwojnicz.pl/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/logo_e-biznes.png"</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                          <div class="col">
                    <div class="gazety_box">
                            <div class="scl_ico gazety"><a href="https://www.lifeandmore.pl/czy-ecommerce-to-sposob-na-sukces-dla-mlodych/" target="_blank"><img src="https://pawelwojnicz.pl/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/lifeandmore.png"</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                          <div class="col">
                    <div class="gazety_box">
                            <div class="scl_ico gazety"><a href="https://biznews.com.pl/biznes/18294-pawel-wojnicz-o-podrozy-za-10-milionow" target="_blank"><img src="https://pawelwojnicz.pl/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/bizneewslgoo.png"</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div> 

                      </div>
        </div>
</section>';
}
```

Footer:
[homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wk4bg.png)
[productpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5Efr.png)

Homepage: https://pawelwojnicz.pl/
Product page: https://pawelwojnicz.pl/produkt/podroz-za-10-milionow/

How can I fix it?

Comment: Check the actual HTML source code - it looks like this in those places, `<div class="gazety_box">
                            <div class="scl_ico gazety"><a href="https://www.lifeandmore.pl/czy-ecommerce-to-sposob-na-sukces-dla-mlodych/" target="_blank"><img </a data-src="https://pawelwojnicz.pl/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/lifeandmore.png" class="lazyload" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="><noscript><img src="https://pawelwojnicz.pl/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/lifeandmore.png"</a></noscript></div>
                    </div>`

Comment: Some sort of lazyload plugin seems to be messing up the output here.

Comment: Hmm. I disabled all plugins besides Woocommerce and it still exist.

Comment: Upon a closer look at the code you have shown above, you appear to have messed that up in the HTML you created yourself already.